# Create new column in Pandas Dataframe with position of row in group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to calculate whether a row in a group of a Pandas Dataframe is at the start, middle, or end of the group (the group is sorted, and one of the columns is the row's index per group). I was thinking of writing a UDF and applying it to each group, but I don't know how to iterate over the rows of the relevant column of the group and then to assign the position to a new column .

I have the following UDF:

```
def add_position_within_group(self,group):
    length_of_group = group['group_index'].max()
    three_lists = self.split_lists_into_three_parts(range(length_of_group))
    for x in group:
        if x["group_index"] in three_lists[0]:
            x["position_in_sequence"] ="start"
        elif x["group_index"] in three_lists[1]:
            x["position_in_sequence"] ="middle"
        elif x["group_index"] in three_lists[2]:
            x["position_in_sequence"] ="end"
```

Which I plan to apply to each group after calling groupby, but I'm not sure if  "for x in group" is the right way to iterate over the rows in the group , or if x["position_in_sequence"] ="start" is the right way to populate a new column for that row.

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: `df['new_col'] = df.groupby('group_name').cumcount()`?

Comment: @ anky I edited the question to make it more specific

Comment: @Quang Hong I don't want the cumulative count, but rather the position of the row in the group, i.e "start", "middle", or "end". I have a function that gives me these categories, so I need to apply it to each row and save the result for that row in a new column.

Comment: aren't you able to get that from `cumcount`?

Comment: @Quang Hoang I do, I've created a new column called group_index, and I use that column to decide whether the row is in the start, middle, or end of the sequence, using a different function (not posted here for the sake of brevity) called self.split_lists_into_three_parts. The part I'm struggling with is saving the result in a new column

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['a'], ['a'], ['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['a']], columns=['A'])

df['group_index'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount()
```

output:

```
    A   group_index
0   a   0
1   a   1
2   a   2
3   b   0
4   b   1
5   a   3
```

You can always make further calculations based on the group_index number.

Hope that helps!

Comment: if you had read the comments you would know this isn't what I'm looking for. I already have the group_index column, Based on this column, I'm trying to determine whether the row falls in the start, middle, or end of the sequence, and then I want to save this category (start, middle, or end) in a new column

Comment: Hi Boris, It seems that there's some important details left unclear. Please clarify the following so we can help you best:

- What do you consider start, middle or end? 

(top 33% / mid 33% / bottom 33%? or perhaps top 50% and bottom 50% with just one element composing the middle assuming it's and odd count)

Comment: I already have a method that takes the maximum value of the column group_index and uses it to assign a part of the list to each index (self.split_lists_into_three_parts) That part of the code is not important (I've tested it and it works). What I wanted to know was how I can apply this method to each row in each group (using the block of code in the question)  and save the result in a new column.